# Access denied to Sql Server mdf file from Visual Studio 2013 data connections

Tags: sql-server, windows, visual-studio

After a fresh install of Windows 8.1 and VS 2013, I noticed that adding a data connection from VS to a Sql server database file didn't work. I tried an existing mdf file.

I installed VS 2013 ultimate and I assume that this installattion includes Sql server tools to open database files (I included that during installation). But I did not install any Sql server edition or express edition.

Error: "unable to open the physical file", "access denied" and also: "an atttempt to attach an auto-named database for file ...mdb failed" and "a database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share".

Well my account is an administrative local account and I run VS in administrative mode. I checked the security of the files and the group 'administrators' has all rights.
Also the mdf file is not corrupt or so and on the local hard drive.

Comment: Are you an admin within the instance of SQL Server your .mdf file related to?

Comment: As a human yes, but the mdf comes from another machine with different account names. Would that be the reason for access denied?

Comment: @Gerard did you fix it? Let us know the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to attach the database to an sql instance, can be done in your connection string